Caps-Lock plus Shift for lower case alphabet
I am using gVim on Microsoft Windows.
Consider two types of alphabet entering:

When the Caps-Lock is off, enter upper case alphabet with Shift-.
When the Caps-Lock is on, enter lower case alphabet with Shift-.

Type 1 is usual. Type 2 is available in many Windows programs, like the Notepad and the HTML input box of my browser that I am currently using, however my gVim doesn't support that. My gVim works that Type 1 perfectly, but Type 2 also giving out upper case letters, instead of lower case letters, like many programs does as mentioned above. Is there a config or something for that? Thank you!
I am not sure if the behavior is identical for gVim in Unix, it might work well in Unix.
I also find that for the 'DOS' vim.exe that work in the Windows cmd.exe, it works well as what I desired. That is, the behavior only happens in gVim . I guess it is because that gVim handles raw keyboard IO itself while the 'DOS' vim.exe gets keyboard events from cmd.exe, which are already filtered? But that's ok, I am just eager to get that behavior in gVim also.

The gVim version I am using:

VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jun 28 2022 13:09:53)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support.

This might make sense. I will try the latest version and update.

The Windows version I am using:

Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
OS build    19045.4412
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19056.1000.0


The advanced keyboard settings I am using, in particular the "To turn off Caps Lock" setting in "Input language hot keys":

To turn off Caps Lock: Press the CAPS LOCK key.

Hot keys for input languages: Left Alt+Shift for 'Between input languages'


gVim features:

+acl                +ex_extra           +mzscheme/dyn       -tcl
+arabic             +extra_search       +netbeans_intg      -termguicolors
+autocmd            -farsi              +num64              +terminal
+autochdir          +file_in_path       +ole                -termresponse
+autoservername     +find_in_path       +packages           +textobjects
+balloon_eval       +float              +path_extra         +textprop
-balloon_eval_term  +folding            +perl/dyn           -tgetent
+browse             -footer             +persistent_undo    +timers
++builtin_terms     +gettext/dyn        +popupwin           +title
+byte_offset        -hangul_input       -postscript         +toolbar
+channel            +iconv/dyn          +printer            +user_commands
+cindent            +insert_expand      +profile            +vartabs
+clientserver       +ipv6               +python/dyn         +vertsplit
+clipboard          +job                +python3/dyn        +vim9script
+cmdline_compl      +jumplist           +quickfix           +viminfo
+cmdline_hist       +keymap             +reltime            +virtualedit
+cmdline_info       +lambda             +rightleft          +visual
+comments           +langmap            +ruby/dyn           +visualextra
+conceal            +libcall            +scrollbind         +vreplace
+cryptv             +linebreak          +signs              -vtp
+cscope             +lispindent         +smartindent        +wildignore
+cursorbind         +listcmds           +sodium/dyn         +wildmenu
+cursorshape        +localmap           +sound              +windows
+dialog_con_gui     +lua/dyn            +spell              +writebackup
+diff               +menu               +startuptime        -xfontset
+digraphs           +mksession          +statusline         -xim
+directx            +modify_fname       -sun_workshop       +xpm_w32
-dnd                +mouse              +syntax             -xterm_save
-ebcdic             +mouseshape         +tag_binary
+emacs_tags         +multi_byte_ime/dyn -tag_old_static
+eval               +multi_lang         -tag_any_white

Compilation: cl -c /W3 /GF /nologo -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CS
COPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL -DFEAT
_IPV6   -DFEAT_XPM_W32 -DHAVE_SODIUM -DDYNAMIC_SODIUM -DDYNAMIC_SODIUM_DLL=\"lib
sodium.dll\" /I "C:\libsodium\include" -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /so
urce-charset:utf-8 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT /D_CR
T_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -D
DYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_MSWIN -DFEAT_DIRECTX -DDYNAMIC_DIRECTX -DFEAT_DIRECTX_COL
OR_EMOJI -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LU
A_DLL=\"lua54.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python
27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python310.dll\
" -DFEAT_MZSCHEME -I "C:\racket\include" -DMZ_PRECISE_GC -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDY
NAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracket3m_da32rk.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libracket3m_da32
rk.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DDYNAMIC_PERL
-DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl532.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL
=\"msvcrt-ruby300.dll\" -DRUBY_VERSION=30 -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjGXOULYHRZi386/ /Zi

Linking: link /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shel
l32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib user32.lib  /mac
hine:i386 version.lib  winspool.lib comctl32.lib  libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  /node
faultlib:lua54.lib  /STACK:8388608  /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:pyt
hon310.lib    winmm.lib WSock32.lib Ws2_32.lib xpm\x86\lib-vc14\libXpm.lib  /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug


I'm using gVim on Windows 10 and I can't reproduce your problem on gVim. Maybe could you share: 1. the gVim version you are using. 2 the Windows version your are using. 3. The advanced keyboard settings you are using (in particular the "To turn off Caps Lock" setting in "Input language hot keys".

@VivianDeSmedt Hi Vivian! Danke for the comment :) I have updated some information. It's good know that it works as I desired on some Windows ... meaning that it might be possible for me to tweak. I guess it's because that my gVim is too old, and I will try the new version and update. Thank you!

I have tested in Vim 9.0 and I can reproduce the problem. With the latest version of Vim 9.1 the problem is gone :-)

@VivianDeSmedt Wow, thank you!!! It's very kind of you to take time testing in the 9.0 version. Even I didn't allocate time to test but decided to schedule it later... thank you so much!

Thanks for the feedback :-)

It is a problem of gVim 9.0.
It has been resolved in gVim 9.1.

Linking to the issues or mailing list threads and commits that solve the problem would be nice.

Indeed. I actually have searched in the commit logs but I didn't found the commit that address that problem specifically (using cap locks as keyword). I suspect that the problem is solved as a side effect of a more general problem but I don't know which one. I could binary search by compiling version but I'm not sure it worth that.

Some candidates (as Git tags): v9.0.1957, v9.0.1826, v9.0.1344/v9.0.1343, v9.0.1220, v9.0.0996, v9.0.0985, v9.0.0912, v9.0.0827, v9.0.0794. (Scanned the output of git log --grep cap v9.0.0000..v9.1.0000)

Mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/cEuwdYxeSwg/m/nAWoIaJwAQAJ, https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/search?q=caps%20lock%20gvim
